# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths cannot reload index path as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I add a image as avatar at indexPath [0,0], and use detailLabel display nickname at indexPath [0,1].
 When use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` indexPath the indexPath [0,1] get a image...

I find when invoke `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` the dequeue cell return nil.

Maybe the [0,0] cell be reuse at [0,1], I don't know why so that.

[image]

The code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _titles = @[@"Avator", @"Nickname"];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(kDelayTime * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        _avator = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cat"];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(kDelayTime * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            _nickName = @"Smallfly";
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        });
    });
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _titles.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *const cellIdenfier = @"cellIdentifier";

    // Why reloadRowsAtIndexPaths [0,0] returned cell is nil?
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdenfier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdenfier];
    }

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self configureCell:cell indexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        NSString *nickName =  _nickName ?: @"nickname";
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = nickName;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = _titles[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    for (UIView *sv in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([sv isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            [sv removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UIImage *avator = _avator ?: [UIImage imageNamed:@"user_profile_avatar"];
    UIImageView *avatorImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:avator];
    ...
    [cell.contentView addSubview:avatorImageView];
}
```

Comment: May I suggest to not tinker with adding/removing `UIImageView` in `configureCell`

Comment: @SwiftArchitect I know you mean, but this is a other question now.

Answer (score 0):

- `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` is a `void` method.
- `dequeueReusableCell` always returns a cell (remove `UITableViewCell alloc`)

#### Objective-C

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray<NSIndexPath *> *)indexPaths
      withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                               cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = 
        [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reuseIdentifier"
        forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}
```

#### Swift 3

```
open func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath],
    with animation: UITableViewRowAnimation)

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = 
        tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier",
        for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
    return cell
}
```

You may want to look at a more recent tutorial or sample code.

Comment: Yeah, I know this way. But even use `tableView.dequeueReusableCell:indexPath` this method still return a new cell when invoke `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Comment: I see. The confusion comes from what `dequeueReusableCell` does: it is the way to reuse view layer objects which are costly. You should not cache cells, which are transient objects. So yes, every time the OS invokes `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it is because it lost it (offscreen, recycled, etc.) and you must return a new, fresh cell. `dequeueReusableCell` is just a way for you to pull that fresh cell from a pool of available cells.